# capture webrtc audio/video stream and send continuously to server while call is running

Tags: webrtc, video-recording

I have implemented audio/video call using webrtc and it is working fine. Now i want to record audio/video same as teams, zoom. For implementing that i need to capture local and remote streams and need to combine both. and then after combining streams i want to send it to server. I need to do it continuously until call is running so that i do not miss any stream in between. So can you suggest how can i do that. i don't know how to capture both streams and how to combine them. If anyone have any idea please let me know. Thanks.